# Facebook OAuth SSO Issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have a JavaEE Application. I am trying to implement OAuth.
But I am facing some strange issues:

1. As per the documentation to manually building the sign in web flow I have to provide a link like this https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1231298371123&display=popup&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fc%2Fportal%2Fauth%2Ffacebook_login%3F&scope=email,public_profile,user_birthday&response_type=code%20token which will open the dialog. But the dialog is not opening.
2. And when the SSO is successful FB is redirecting to the url given above but the problem is FB is appending the query strings like state, code, etc with **#**. Something like: http://localhost:8080/c/portal/auth/facebook_login?#state=ASDASDASDASD&access_token=EAANXZAlBTi........ Because for this I cannot get the parameters in Java.

Do any one came across this kind of issue. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question right but if you want to read the string after # you can use the following code

```
URI uri = new URI("http://test.com/#something=some");
String fragment = uri.getFragment();
```

fragment will be everything after #